# What's the essential definition of resonance of Schrodinger operator?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, schrodinger-operators

Rencently, I am reading some articles about time decay estimates or Strichartz estimates for Schrodinger equations with potential. When considering Strichartz estimates for potential $V$ with decay $|x|^{-2-\varepsilon}$, Rodnianski & Schlag said in [Time decay for solutions of Schrödinger equations with rough and time-dependent potentials](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Rodnianski&s5=time%20decay%20for%20solutions%20of&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) that the Strichartz estimte (nonendpoint case) holds if we assume the initial data $u_0 \in P_{[0,\infty)} X$, where $X$ is the total space. Moreover, in view of $0$ will contribute negative effection on the esimates, we should assume that $0$ is neither eigenvalue nor the resonance of  $H=-\Delta+V$.

I am wondering what's the precise definition of resonance? Because I have seen at least three definitions of it, but what definition is the most essential?

**definition (version 1: [Rodnianski & Schalg: Time decay for solutions of Schrödinger equations with rough and time-dependent potentials](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Rodnianski&s5=time%20decay%20for%20solutions%20of&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq))**  A resonance is a distribution solution to $H \psi=0$ so that $\psi \notin L^2$ but $(1+|x|^2)^{-\frac{\sigma}{2}} \psi(x) \in L^2$ for any $\sigma>\frac{1}{2}$.

**definition (version 2: [Artzi & Klainerman: Decay and regularity for the Schrödinger equation](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Ben-Artzi&s5=decay%20and%20regularity%20for%20the%20Schrodinger%20equation&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) )** zero is said to be a resonance of $H$ if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a $0 \not= \psi \in H^{2,-1-\varepsilon}$ such taht $H\psi=0$.

**definition (version 3: [Nakanish & Schalg: Invariant manifolds and Dipersive Hamiltonian Evolution Equations](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=Schlag&s5=invariant%20manifolds&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=2847755))** in odd dimensions, the reslovent $(H-z^2)^{-1}$ can be expanded by $(H-z^2)^{-1}=B_{-2}z^{-2}+B_{-1}z^{-1}+B_0+B_1z +... B_k z^k +R_k(z)$, where the expansion is in $L^{2,-1/2-\varepsilon} \to L^{2,1/2+\varepsilon}$ sense, we say $0$ is neither eigenvalue nor the resonance of $H$ iff $B_{-2}=B_{-1}=0$.

and so on...

I just know the aim of ruling out the resonance is to ensure the "good" behavior of $(H-z)^{-1}$ near $z=0$.

However, are the three definitions of resonance above equivalent to each other? Especially for **definition 2** and **definition 1**. I think the **definition 2** is a little peculiar, but [Rodnianski and Schalg： "time decay estimates..."](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Rodnianski&s5=time%20decay%20for%20solutions%20of&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) cited the results in [Artzi & Klainermann: "decay and regularity..."](http://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=Ben-Artzi&s5=decay%20and%20regularity%20for%20the%20Schrodinger%20equation&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) to support their result. But at least we note that $\text{definition 1} \subset \text{definition 2}$, thus $\text{(definition 2)}^c \subset \text{(definition 1)}^c$. So we can see that if $0$ is not resonance in **def 1**, the conclusion that $0$ is not resonance in the sense of **def 2** will not hold necessarily.

I am struggled about it, if someone has known something about it, please tell me, thank you!